# 'CameraDevice' does not contain a definition for 'CameraDirection'

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I'm using code to switch camera front and back. But now this code does not work. How to fix this?

```
if (CameraDevice.Instance.GetCameraDirection() == CameraDevice.CameraDirection.CAMERA_BACK)
        {
            SelectCamera(CameraDevice.CameraDirection.CAMERA_FRONT);
        }
        else 
        {
            SelectCamera(CameraDevice.CameraDirection.CAMERA_BACK);
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see from the [Api Reference](https://library.vuforia.com/content/vuforia-library/en/reference/unity/classVuforia_1_1CameraDevice.html) there is no `CameraDirection` in `CameraDevice` anymore.

You can try  `VuforiaConfiguration.Instance.Vuforia.CameraDirection` instead.

More likely it does not work because you updated your Vuforia and  front camera is not supported anymore so you should be using older version of Vuforia for this.